# Get original query from Django

Tags: django, hmac

I would like to get the original query (in the exact same format as sent) from Django.

Currently, django sends me a query dict object, wherein if I do querydict.urlencode(), I get the query back, but in a different format from what is sent, since dictionary mangles the positions.

For GET, we can use, request.get_full_path().

I have not found a mechanism for POST.

I require it since I am doing a HMAC, and for HMAC, the exact positioning of fields are important.

Regards

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is solved.

We can use raw_post_data for that. Forgot about that.